# Compute Gradient of some multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Let $\mathcal{A} \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear operator and $h \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice continuously differentiable function. Compute the gradient of the following functions:
\begin{align}
f \left( x , y \right) & = \left\langle y , \nabla h \left( x \right) \right\rangle , \\
g \left( x , z \right) & = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert \mathcal{A}^{*} \left( \mathcal{A} x - z \right) \right\rVert ^{2} ,
\end{align}
where $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are given.

It can be seen that $\partial_{y} f \left( x , y \right) = \nabla h \left( x \right)$. However, for $\partial_{x} f \left( x , y \right)$ I do not know how to start. If $\nabla h \left( x \right) = \mathcal{A} x$ for example, then I can rewrite $f \left( x , y \right) = \left\langle \mathcal{A}^{*} y , x \right\rangle$ and so $\partial_{x} f \left( x , y \right) = \mathcal{A}^{*} y$. But it's not always the case as I have no further information on $h$.

For $g$ I rewrite as
\begin{align}
g \left( x , z \right) & = \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} x \right\rVert ^{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \left\lVert z \right\rVert ^{2} + \left\langle \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} x , \mathcal{A}^{*} z \right\rangle
\end{align}
and so $\partial_{x} g \left( x , z \right) = \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} x + \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \mathcal{A}^{*} z , \partial_{z} g \left( x , z \right) = z + \mathcal{A} \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} x$. These formula looks really weird to me so I'm not really sure that I am corrected

Comment: That looks like a problem you've been assigned to solve.  What is **your** question?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang sr about that. I updated my question

Comment: thanks for filling in your work.  For problems like this I tend to “cheat” by writing it out in indices.  Then once you've figured it out, clean up your argument so it doesn't require indices.

Comment: You have really worked on the subject! Let us take $n=2$ and compute with indices: as $f(x,y)=y_1 \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}+y_2 \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}$, let us come back to the definition of differentiation: for a fixed $y$: $f(x+\delta,y)-f(x)=y_1 [(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}|_{x_1+\delta_1}-(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_1}|_{x_1}]+y_2 [(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}|_{x_2+\delta_2}-(\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_12}|_{x_2}]$+terms in $o(||\delta||^2)$= dot product of $(y_1,y_2)$ with $(\nabla^2 (h|_{x_1},\nabla^2 (h|_{x_2})$ which is the looked for derivative.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for your help. I knew what to do now :D